# Trouble creating app.yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, app.yaml

Installed google app engine for PHP. Having trouble creating app.yaml file.

My application -Public has 3 subdirectories->

```
A.html
B.includes
C.templates
```

html has the following contents->

```
A.html
    1.app.yaml~ 
    2.favicon.ico 
    3.index.php  
    4.login.php 
    5.password.php
    6.quote.php
    7.buy.php  
    8.history.php    
    9.portfolio.php   
    10.register.php
    11.logout.php  
    12.portfolio.php  
    13.sell.php

    and following three subdirectories->
        a.css        b.img          c.js
```

where a,b,c are for css ,images and javasript respectively.

the subdirectory includes has the following contents->

```
B.includes
    1.config.php  
    2.constants.php  
    3.constants.php  
    4.functions.php
```

and the subdirectory templates has the following contents->

```
C.templates
        1.apology.php                 
    2.portfolio.php
    3.buy_template.php            
    4.price.php
    5.dump.php         
    6.history_template.php   
    7.quote_template.php
    8.footer.php        
    9.login_template.php     
    10.register_template.php
    11.password_template.php  
    12.sell_template.php
    13.header.php
```

Comment: What does your app.yaml file look like?

Comment: And what part of the site does not work?

Comment: My application is public , and the main page is index.php, but I don't know how the handlers work, I read it on the google app engine page, but instructions are not that clear.

Comment: If you update your question with the contents of your app.yaml file, someone may be able to tell you what is wrong with it.